# How to show missing values in legend of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a barplot with `ggplot2`. My problem is missing data which is plottet at least but missing in the legend.

For example, if M is my data:

```
 aim = c(rep(1, 28), 0, rep(1,7))
 type = c(rep(F, 10), rep(T, 4), rep(F, 4), NA, NA, rep(T, 5), rep(F, 12))
 M = data.frame(aim, type)
```

Then, I can get a barplot like this:

```
 g <- ggplot(M, aes(as.character(aim)))
 g + geom_bar(aes(fill=as.character(type)), position= "dodge")  + scale_fill_discrete(name="Type", breaks=c("TRUE", "FALSE", "NA"), labels=c("existing", "not existing", "missing values")) + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("bad", "good"))
```

[image: Result of this code leads into a graphic without an explanation for the grey bar chart.]

**Question:** The legend ignores missing values. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Transform them to string, `df[is.na(df)] <- "NA"`

Comment: Only this is an option? I hoped for an command like show.na = TRUE....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
aim = c(rep(1, 28), 0, 0, rep(1,7))
type = c(rep(F, 10), rep(TRUE, 4), rep(F, 4), NA, NA, rep(TRUE, 5), rep(F, 12))
M = data.frame(aim, type)
M[is.na(M$type),] <- 'NA'
g <- ggplot(M, aes(as.character(aim)))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=as.character(type)), position= "dodge")  + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Type", breaks=c("TRUE", "FALSE", "NA"),    
    labels=c("existing", "not existing", "missing values")) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("bad", "good"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice suggestion. Not really what I think about, but better than everything else I saw until today.